# How to turn off a light sensor LED light?

Tags: electrical, led

I've got a light on my condo building and I'd like to figure out how to turn it off. It's currently operated by an automatic light sensor (turns off when it gets dark).

I want to setup better lighting for parties/etc.

Do these white screws do anything? Is it possible to hire an electrician to replace this box with a switch system (when turned on uses light sensor, when off overrides to off).

I'll have to get / post a photo of the light (it's an outdoor LED floodlight).
[image]

Comment: I'm sure there's a valid reason this was installed in the first place, though I don't really understand why a light would go off when it's dark (unless you mean that the sensor goes off, so the light goes on). If the original reason still makes sense per all members of your condo, you may want to install a system in parallel instead of replacing this one. If this isn't needed anymore, you'll want to involve your condo association (unless you're asking on their behalf).

Comment: The only thing I could see that makes sense is that the light turns on when it is dark and you would prefer that this light is off so you can have different "mood lighting". Is that correct? If so, a picture of the light fixture might also be beneficial to see if there is something could be done to disable/block the light temporarily without requiring permanent modification (such as unscrewing a bulb on nights you have parties).

Answer (score 6):

The white "screws", are knockout plugs. A knockout is simply a hole where conduit, cable, wire, or a device can attach/enter the box. A knockout plug, is used to fill unused knockouts.

Here is a similar box cover with the knockouts unplugged.

[image: Unplugged Knockouts]

This allows you to attach devices, like lamp holders and motion sensors.

[image: Lamp Holder][image: Motion Sensor][image: Box Cover with Lamp Holders Attached]

Any extra holes would be filled with a plug.

[image: Knockout Plug]

---

## Professional Help

You should be able to hire an Electrician to install a switch as you mention, but it would depend on if you have the legal right to (own vs. rent, etc.)

---